# Interop DLL does not show Events when they are visible to other .NET languages

Tags: .net, f#

I've generated an interop DLL.  Works fine.  Oddly though, the events which are visible in C# are not visible in F#.  Fortunately the add/remove functions exist in the DLL to add/remove my handlers.  So there is a work around.

What I don't understand is why I would not be able to see the actual event parameters themselves since they are part of the interface.  Is there anything special that must be done when generating the interop for usage in F#?  It is as though the access modifier for the events is private or protected when viewing in F#, but not in C#

Comment: Add() is required F# syntax: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233189.aspx

Comment: I don't even see the events i.e. `event Click` is defined in the interface which is visible in C# but is not visible in F#

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you are using the Client profile, switch to the full .Net 4.0 profile in project properties and try that.  In VS2010 thats the default setting and it catches a lot of people out.

Another possibility is that it is a non standard event implementation, I encountered that in MonoTouch yesterday.

Failing those I would have a look at the dll with reflector or similar and see whats what with the generated code.